# How to run exit-independent code in Dart?

Tags: dart

I'm willing to execute `pub get` in background ignoring if the process that started it exited o terminated. Something like this:

```
// ... pubspec.yaml code changes
executeInBackground("pub get"); //async call, returns a Future
exit(0);
```

How could I do this without using the Process.runSync() blocking call? (I want the program to end ASAP)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Process.start](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.2/dart-io/Process/start.html) doc and its `mode` parameter.

```dart
import 'dart:io';

main() async {
  final p = await Process.start(
    'pub',
    ['get'],
    runInShell: true,
    mode: ProcessStartMode.DETACHED, //all the magic is here
  );
  print(p.pid);
}
```

Comment: It's "ProcessStartMode.detached" with lower case.
(BTW it's very important to await Process.start if you missed it. Else it won't work.)